# use appendTo() and switch to add content from variables to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm trying to create a page with a main content div, where users can select different options to add different additional content.  That added content will then offer options to add yet more different stuff.  The end goal is to make a short interactive story.

Edited to reflect a partially new approach that I still can't get to work.

My current code looks like this:

```
<div id="ongoingStory">
   <p>You're standing in a place.  There are whatever items here and one or more exits.</p>  
   <p>Do you want to take <span id="action1">action 1</span> or <span id="action 2">action 2</span>?</p>
</div>

var oneResult = "<p>You take action 1, and some stuff happens.  You can then take <span id=\"action3\">action 3</span> or <span id=\"action4\">action 4</span>.</p>";
var anotherResult = "<p>You take action 2, and other stuff happens.  You can then take <span id=\"action5\">action 5</span> or <span id=\"action6\">action 6</span>.</p>";

var root;
var branch;

function addToStory( root,branch ) {
   $( "#" + root ).addClass( "disabled" );
   $( branch ).appendTo( "#ongoingStory" ).hide().fadeIn(1000);
}

document.getElementById( "ongoingStory" ).addEventListener("click", moveAlong, false);

function moveAlong(e) {
   if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
      switch (e.target.id) {
         case action1:addToStory( action1,oneResult );break;
         case action2:addToStory( action2,anotherResult );break;
         case action3:addToStory( action3,otherResult );break;
         case action4:addToStory( action4,yetOtherResult );break;
      };
   };
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

The page loads without any errors, but nothing happens when I click an action in the content that initially loads inside the `ongoingStory` div.  The console then tells me "ReferenceError: action3 is not defined."  Of course it isn't, because the content including that action/id tag isn't being added.  What I don't understand is why it's not appending the content in the first place.  I've thought that maybe I'm not referencing the spans' ID's correctly, but in that case, I'd expect the switch to get stuck at action1.

Comment: append() and appendTo() are the same thing, it's just a difference of who's the parent. You are declaring variables root and branch globally, but they are local in your function. When #root is clicked, it has no idea what branch is.

To confuse things further, you are assigning an additional event handler to "#root" every time addToStory is run.

Comment: It's annoying when you completely change the question/problem days after it has already been answered. Please post it as a new question when you have a new problem instead of editing, it causes unnecessary confusion to other people viewing and downvotes to answers that were actually correct for the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few issues in your code.  We've [covered the best practices in the chat room.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18925457#18925457)  As far as the *actual* issue, you're missing some quotes:

```
case action1:addToStory( action1,oneResult );break;
```

needs to become:

```
        case 'action1':
            addToStory('action1', oneResult);
            break;
```

(same for all the other actions)

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/somekittens/70qebhbm/